# How to set root location for AngularJS router?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to start navigation from `http://mysite.com/hello/world`, not from site root.

e.g.

```js
$routeProvider
  .when('/myurl', {
    templateUrl: 'mytmpl.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl'
  });
```

should react when my url is `http://mysite.com/hello/world/myurl`

How could I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add base tag to the main HTML file that is being served when user navigates to `http://example.com/hello/world`:

```html
<base href="/hello/world/" />
```

More info can be found at [Developer Guide / Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: Changing of site base is not correct decision.  I would like to do something like `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/public/search/"})`. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Backbone methods. And you did not explain why the base tag solution is not a correct decision?

Comment: It change behaviour of all static.. I would like to change base only for router.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a basetag also creates issue, double time gets appended.

By adding a (.) for root, in template url as below:
  templateUrl: './mytmpl.html' - resolves the issue