# AngularJS URL get escaped with $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an AngularJS application, it works well with hash URL.
If I click on an anchor `<a href="#/3125/">` then the URL is updated to `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#/3125/` which is desired.

Now I plan to change the URL to HTML5 mode, so I configured the application with below code

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['demoResources']);
    demoApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Unfortunately, this time if I click on the same anchor, I got URL escaped as `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#%2F3125%2F` thus the link is broken. However, the expected URL is `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html/3125`.

Does anyone know why this is not working? I am using Angular 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `<base>` tag in the `<head>` section of your application :

```
<base href="/app"/>
```

See the "Relative Links" section in the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location) documentation.

See also [AngularJS subdirectory routing not working, with <base> tag applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368547/angularjs-subdirectory-routing-not-working-with-base-tag-applied)