# angularjs route not working without last slash /

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I've configured `$routeProvider` this way

```
miNgAppplication.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "Base/FirstPage",
            controller: "miNgControllerFirstPage"
        })
}]);
```

This works when I insert the url WITH a final slash, for example "http://localhost/myApp/". It adds to the URl a "#/" and displays the correct content (final URL is "http://localhost/myApp/#/")
When I don't use the slash it doesn't work, basically it's because it changes the URL incorrectly
"http://localhost/myApp" -> "http://localhost/myApp#/".

What should I do? Have I used the first `when` parameter incorrectly to define the first page? Or do I need to do some correction?

I've already tried to add `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(true);` but it not working (not sure I did it correctly, first line become `miNgAppplication.config(['$routeProvider', '$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function ($routeProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {`, right?).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [otherwise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) method to set the default url when nothing matches.

```
miNgAppplication.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "Base/FirstPage",
            controller: "miNgControllerFirstPage"
        });
    $routeProvider.otherwise('/'); // <-- this should take the user to the first page.
}]);
```

Comment: this doesn't work correctly, I guess because the url is misinterpreted. The exact url is `http://localhost/apps/TestClient`. It convert it to `http://localhost/apps/TestClient#/` and the `otherwise` try to redirect but the `templateUrl` is somehow added wrong. It doesn't look for `http://localhost/apps/TestClient/Base/FirstPage` but for `http://localhost/apps/Base/FirstPage` generating an erro in the console. Probably when URL is /apps/TestClient/#/ it undestrand that the base is /apps/TestClient/, but when it is /apps/TestClient#/ it think the base is only /apps/

Comment: hmm have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319715/how-to-set-root-location-for-angularjs-router

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I didn't find an easy solution, I decided to listen for route events and change the url when it ends with #/ but not with /#/. This is an ugly solution but at least it works

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a working solution. I hope someone can give me an hint, meanwhile I solved this (ugly) way. Basically I listen on $route events and redirect when necessary.

```
miNgAppplication.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, next, current) {
        if (miLib.endsWith(window.location.href, "#/") && !miLib.endsWith(window.location.href, "/#/")) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var newLink = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf("#/")) + "/#/";
            console.clear();
            window.location.href = newLink;
        }
    });
});
```